# Wordpress blog from godaddy running on subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, dnsimple

I have a rails app with a domain like`myapp.com` running on heroku with the domain nameservers at DNsimple.com I want to create a wordpress blog hosted on GoDaddy. I found an article to do this (kinda) at

https://medium.com/@parterburn/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8

But my setup is a little different because the domain is on the DNsimple service and I can't seem to get it to work. According to this tutorial, my domain for the blog should be something like myapp.service.com but I can't seem to do that with GoDaddy especially since the domain name nameservers are at DNsimple.

Other than this 1 piece I have everything else setup. I am using the rack-reverse-proxy gem and all of that works fine except this domain issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myapp.service.com is the URL to the blog. It can be anything you like. When you stand up a new Wordpress install on GoDaddy it most likely will give you an ugly "temporary" URL which you can use. Flywheel also allows you to have basic auth, which is why the user and pass are included in the reverse-proxy setup. The auth also slightly helps with SEO so Google will only know your myapp.com/blog URL exists.

Comment: So the flywheel service is not hosting but allowing the url to go to a sub-directory?

Comment: So this technique is dependent on the redirect and masking the real redirect domain is that right?